# Vary or differ?

Tags: meaning

"The equipment used on operations may vary from that used in training."
I have a feeling the writer should use "differ".
Is it because attributes of the equipment are different like "range varies with temperature and humidity"?  Meaning the same gun has different qualities depending on the situation.

Or "The price of a used 2010 Ford Focus RS varies with mileage" so the higher mileage means a lower price, here we're talking about a number of cars on the market.

Comment: We usually say [**YMMV**](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C2CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&source=hp&ei=4By6W73iIIPWsAGakZrACw&q=YMMv&oq=YMMv&gs_l=psy-ab.13..35i39k1j0i20i263k1l2j0l7.2560.2560.0.4067.3.2.0.0.0.0.91.91.1.2.0....0...1c.2.64.psy-ab..1.2.175.6...86.OyoDYVNQ1Vs), but it could just as well have been **YMMD** if that hadn't already been co-opted for *You made my day!*

Comment: Nah it can't be that simple. There has to be someone who can decide on word choice and usage.

Comment: Yes, it's true that as a *competent* native speaker, there are contexts where I would definitely choose one over the other. For example, I'd almost always go for ***vary*** in your "price" example because it carries stronger implications of some *algebraic* relationship between price and mileage.  In your "equipment" example things are less clear-cut. To my mind, ***vary*** might be considered more "reassuring" to the students (because a "variation" may be more recognisably "similar" than something which could be totally ***different***). But "differ" might be better as a ***warning***.

Comment: ...but you could work all that out for yourself by considering the underlying core senses of being a (potentially, *similar*) ***variety*** of something, or being (potentially, *completely*) ***different***. But explanations at that level are better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm sorry but why is this off-topic? Word choice and usage is clearly on-topic.